# How to sort a table by two columns crosswise

Tags: sql

I have a table that belongs to a person's cell phone texting called 'Ali'. He received text messages from people and sent his text message reply to those people.

`MessageTable` looks like this:

| id | sendDate | sendTime | sender | receiver |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1397/01/02 | 10:02 | Karim | Ali |
| 2 | 1398/05/09 | 05:30 | Hamed | Ali |
| 3 | 1398/06/07 | 05:10 | Majid | Ali |
| 4 | 1398/08/09 | 06:12 | Ali | Karim |
| 5 | 1399/02/01 | 07:15 | Ali | Saeed |
| 6 | 1399/07/02 | 08:51 | Parsa | Ali |
| 7 | 1399/08/06 | 12:20 | Ali | Karim |
| 8 | 1399/09/04 | 20:01 | Ali | Hamed |
| 9 | 1399/12/08 | 22:05 | Asgar | Ali |
| 10 | 1400/01/01 | 23:11 | Majid | Ali |
| 11 | 1400/02/13 | 14:10 | Karim | Ali |
| 12 | 1400/04/05 | 16:25 | Ali | Hamed |
| 12 | 1400/06/12 | 22:25 | Ali | Majid |
| 12 | 1400/07/24 | 08:25 | Saeed | Ali |

I want the table to be arranged in such a way that, firstly, all the text messages that Ali had with each person are arranged separately, and secondly, the date and time are displayed in order.
something like this:

| id | sendDate | sendTime | sender | receiver |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1397/01/02 | 10:02 | Karim | Ali |
| 4 | 1398/08/09 | 06:12 | Ali | Karim |
| 7 | 1399/08/06 | 12:20 | Ali | Karim |
| 11 | 1400/02/13 | 14:10 | Karim | Ali |
| 2 | 1398/05/09 | 05:30 | Hamed | Ali |
| 8 | 1399/09/04 | 20:01 | Ali | Hamed |
| 12 | 1400/04/05 | 16:25 | Ali | Hamed |
| 3 | 1398/06/07 | 05:10 | Majid | Ali |
| 10 | 1400/01/01 | 23:11 | Majid | Ali |
| 12 | 1400/06/12 | 22:25 | Ali | Majid |
| 5 | 1399/02/01 | 07:15 | Ali | Saeed |
| 12 | 1400/07/24 | 08:25 | Saeed | Ali |
| 6 | 1399/07/02 | 08:51 | Parsa | Ali |
| 9 | 1399/12/08 | 22:05 | Asgar | Ali |

I need SQL code, Can every body help me?

Comment: I am not sure if SQL has this, but you might want to look into comparators. If yes, I could use the objects of calls that are displayed here and sort an array of them accordingly before turning it into a String[][] to display here in the list.

Comment: Hi galliadii, Please guide me in any way you can. Thank

Comment: If I understood this correctly u want to get an output of a query and not the table being like that correct? If That is the case I might see something like the following:
SELECT * FROM MessageTable GroupBY sender, receiver; ORDERBY sendDate

Comment: Hope that SELECT query helped u. The idea there is to select all as u want all the columns of the table then group them by sender and receiver so u get the groups u want and then order those groups by the sendDate in a ascending way so that you can have the first calls then the last ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order first by the first timestamp for each contact.
Then the contact.  Then the date & time.

Without window functions, it's something like this :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM messages t
JOIN (
  SELECT 
   (CASE WHEN receiver = 'Ali' THEN sender ELSE receiver END) AS contact, 
   MIN(TIMESTAMP(sendDate, sendTime)) AS minTs
  FROM messages
  WHERE 'Ali' IN (sender, receiver)
  GROUP BY (CASE WHEN receiver = 'Ali' THEN sender ELSE receiver END)
) q ON q.contact IN (t.sender, t.receiver)
WHERE 'Ali' IN (t.sender, t.receiver)
ORDER BY q.minTs, q.contact, t.sendDate, t.sendTime;
```

Comment: Hi LukStorms, I check your solution, it was ok. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated column with a CASE statement that sets its value to the sender if the receiver is Ali and to the receiver if the sender is Ali.

Sort by this column and the date

Answer (score 0):

I come from Java. I do not use SQL. But I had a similar problem a while ago and I will just explain how I solved it:
I created an ArrayList of Objects of the type of Class. In Your case these would the the calls, or messages. These objects have specific data.
I then would use a model to add data in the list and change the model, not the list.
I would then create an 2D array of Strings that contain the Data.
When you change the data, you just rearrange the way the 2D Array is created.
Also use a loop to create the 2D Array so your list can be infinitly big.
I used all the trigger words. You may want to do the research on how to do it with SQL yourself. If it does help, let me know.